# pandas dataframe float point issues

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point

I have a column with float values such as `600.0750, 600.2274, 600.3798, 600.5322`.I rounded the values to 3 decimal places and then applied the `diff()` function to that column which gave me values `0.1524,0.1524` and `0.1524`.To remove the duplicates from the output, I applied `drop_duplicates`. I was expecting to see only `0.1524` but in actual I got `0.1524,0.1524,0.1524`.

So I store the output values in another dataframe df_diff and I do `df_diff.iloc[2]` which gives me  `0.15239999999994325` and for `df_diff.iloc[3]` I get `0.15240000000005693`.

I go back and do the same for original df and I get `600.07500000000005`. So even when I am rounding, the values are not getting rounded. What can I do to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: floating point math is not precise....

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Floating-point math is well defined. There is more to this question than just throwing up your hands and saying we do not know how floating-point works.

Comment: Just FYI (not a solution to the larger problem), your statement that “the values are not getting rounded” is likely incorrect. Quite likely, the values are being rounded, but the final results still must be represented in 64-bit binary floating-point. So the exact values 600.0750, 600.2274, 600.3798, and 600.5322 become 600.075000000000045474735088646411895751953125, 600.227399999999988722265698015689849853515625, 600.3798000000000456566340290009975433349609375, and 600.5321999999999889041646383702754974365234375.

Comment: @EricPostpischil sure. The solution here is to either use a function like `np.isclose` to drop duplicates based on some epsilon - although, I'm not sure if the built-in method can be used together with `np.isclose`, or perhaps more simply, not round until the very end.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The problem I see with trying to combine `isclose` with `drop_duplicates` is that `is_close` is not an equivalence relation. Suppose your number are [100+epsilon/2, 100+epsilon,100+3*epsilon/2 ... 110].  Does it drop half the numbers? All? None?

Comment: @Acccumulation yes, you are right. I think multiplying by 10000, maybe in combination with flooring, then using `astype(np.int)` and then working with those numbers to do the diffing/comparing, or again, simply waiting to round until the end.

Comment: yes multiplied by 10000 and converted to int solved the problem. Thankyou all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you rounded to three decimal places, but your numbers have four. The following assumes that four is the correct number.

There are several options. First, you can try not rounding until right before you try to drop duplicates. If that doesn't work, if you aren't too particular about the exact level of precision you're rounding to, you can round to a power of 2, such as 2**14. A second option is to use the https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html module. A third option is to multiply the numbers by 10000 and then round them to integers. If you want the original numbers back, then you can divide them by 10000 again.

Comment: What is relevant for dropping duplicates is not whether the result of the rounding is the same as how they appear as four-digit decimal numbers, what's relevant is whether, given two numbers that display as the same four-digit number, they both get rounded to the same number. Since rounding doesn't in general distribute over other operations, it should be done last.